# Password History check in openldap

Tags: passwords, history

Password History check in openldap not working when I am using SHA-256 password hashing in openldap.

So I am sending clear text password from my java application to openLDAP and it is storing as SHA-256 hashed form on its own.
whenever I am changing password, openLDAP is storing the previous password in pwdHistory.
There is no problem in that but when I am changing password with the same password previously used it is taking up without throwing any error.
I am struggling to make it work for few weeks. Please somebody help me.

My environment details:
OpenLDAP 2.4.38
RHEL 6

Following details also mentioned in slapd.conf

include ../etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

password-hash {SHA256}

overlay ppolicy

ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=pwdpolicies,dc=my-domain,dc=com"

ppolicy_hash_cleartext

my password policy:

dn: cn=Default,ou=pwdpolicies,dc=my-domain,dc=com

objectClass: pwdPolicy

objectClass: person

objectClass: top

cn: Default

sn: Default

pwdAttribute: userPassword

pwdMinAge: 0

pwdInHistory: 5

pwdFailureCountInterval: 0

pwdLockout: TRUE

pwdLockoutDuration: 0

pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE

pwdExpireWarning: 0

pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0

pwdMustChange: FALSE

pwdSafeModify: FALSE

Kindly let me know if I have to give me more information to nail down the issue. 
Please Please Please someone help me on this. I am badly need a solution on this.

Comment: I am giving the same password "Password11" many times and after that I printed the pwdHistory attribute values in my java code to check. 
<br>Surprisingly encrypted values for same password it is storing as different values like below:<br>
{SHA256}oghigenebwtKa2r2DGapn+zvz8YyKOMR
{SHA256}5G3PmOgYb68C6vLIUl7hLVBc62lZaG0s
{SHA256}0IV1ocGpT2WNcj/ZS39TCwZRbil+UJht
{SHA256}iVsU4uvp7gydIE1x/I5cpE/tiduwxjzl
{SHA256}xZe6GtFWubixm0Xb+9cVTdWLIJEnSsM8

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also facing similar issue...